# fql multi query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

`FB.api(

{

 method: 'fql.query',

 query: 'select uid,name from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 ='+me.id+') AND current_location='+me.location.name

 },function(data) {
alert(data);`

}

iam trying to get the friends based on the current user location.But  this query is not working? Is there any possible way to write this as a single query?
I need to loop all the datas to check the current location else ,but it takes time for checking it.So iam looking for single query to get the datas? Could any one help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an idea, 
firstly your application requires `user_location` and `friends_location` as permissions.

Why don't you modify your query to something like this

```
FB.api(
{
   method: 'fql.query',
   query: 'select uid,name,current_location from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 ='+me.id+')
   },function(data) { alert(data);
}
```

The idea is to get current_location of user and user's friends and then do your filtering.

Hope this helps

Comment: but i need to run a for loop for finding the current location.So iam now accesing the freindlist which facebook provides for current area.Anyways thanks for your reply.